# How to 301 redirect from subdomain directory to main domain directory?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have such redirect here:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gidranty.ispytanie01.ru
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ispytanie01.ru/vodosnabzhenie/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But now I need a little bit complex redirect. If user prints "gidranty.ispytanie01.ru/spb" I need to redirect him to "http://ispytanie01.ru/spb/vodosnabzhenie".

I tried to use something like this:

```
Redirect 301 http://gidranty.ispytanie01.ru/spb http://ispytanie01.ru/spb/vodosnabzhenie
```

But it doesnt work. Need some advice :)

Comment: If use http://gidranty.ispytanie01.ru/spb/vodosnabzhenie, it goes to http://ispytanie01.ru/vodosnabzhenie/spb/vodosnabzhenie. Close, but not as I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gidranty.ispytanie01.ru [NC]
RewriteRule ^spb(/.*)?$ http://ispytanie01.ru/spb/vodosnabzhenie$1 [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gidranty.ispytanie01.ru [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ispytanie01.ru/vodosnabzhenie/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Main problem is not the redirect to /spb. Main problem, that I cant redirect from link with spb to one page, and if link without spd - to another :)